# If a range of cell is blank, i want to fill it with some text. How to do that?

Tags: excel, vba

I've blank cells in between in column M. Also I've some values in column A. If column M is blanks, i should fill it with the text 'XYZ'. How can I do that? I tried following things.

```
Dim i As Integer
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastcell_number = ActiveCell.Row
For i = 1 To lastcell_number
IF ELSE part here 
Next i
```

IF ELSE.

```
If IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) = True Then

Range("A1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "XYZ"

End If
```

help me with if else part. How to wrrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) option.

For column M:

```
on error resume next
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    .columns(12).specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "xyz"
end with
on error goto 0
```

I'm afraid I'm unclear on what you want to do with column A.

Comment: It's filling values till 160. Don't know where this number came from. Any idea?

Comment: Row 160 is where Excel thinks the row limit of the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) is. Given no sample data or a reference to any column populated down as far as you wanted to go, I had to make my own guess as to an appropriate measure of halting the blank fill before it got to the bottom of the worksheet. Typically, you would pick the last populated row of a known column or possibly the number of rows in the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx). I just has no way to know that

Answer (score 0):

I assume column A is where you determine your list's row limit:

```
Dim RowLimit As Long
RowLimit = Cells(Rows.Count, [A1].Column).End(xlUp).Row

Range("M1", Cells(RowLimit, [M1].Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "XYZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim rangexl as range
Dim cellr as range

Set Rangxl = range("a1:a"(whatever)

For each cellr in rangexl
If cellr.value ="" then cellr.value= "xyz"
Next cellr
Loop

Whatever can be a fixed range or varable. Count or anything you choose.